# Wordpress WebSite is jumps while scrolling bottom

Tags: gallery

my following wordpress pages are jumps while scolling down

1.http://madhurihoney.com/d-rajeevi/

2.http://madhurihoney.com/blog/image-gallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some css that is conflicting and causing the issue when the top menu sticks absolute on scroll down and the header hides.

In your media.css on line 340 you have:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){
    .main-navigation {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Changing that in live dev tools to:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){
    .main-navigation {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        float: none !important;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Seems to fix the issue and make it smooth again.

Comment: how to edit media.css whether i need to use the ftp? can a add the css at custome css option?

Comment: You can add it as custom css if you like or wp-admin -> appearance should allow you to edit that file.

I have edited my css that you can put into custom css above which includes the !important on the end of float which will overwrite the existing css if you are using custom css

Comment: thank you for the anser